# Jquery to compare the value of dynamically generated control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am developing a mvc4 jquery application. I have dynamically generated hidden field and I am binding some value to it as below.

```
@foreach (var group in Model.detailsbyclientId) {
    <tr>
        <td> @group.clientName </td>
        <td> @group.employeeId </td>
        <td> @group.employeeName </td>
        <td>@group.Nationality</td>
        <td> @group.documentType </td>
        <td scope="col">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons" value="View Document" onclick="showDocumentData('@group.upld_Id');" />
        </td>
        <td id="Hi">@group.currentStatus</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" id="Status" value="@group.currentStatus"/></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
}
```

In some point of time the value of `@group.currentStatus` will be NotVerified. For example if I generate 5 rows of data, the value of all 5 rows will be NotVerified. In such a case I want to display some message or else display nothing. So whenever all rows of the data are holding the same value then I want to display a message. This is my jquery function and I have used below logic.

```
var list = new Array();
$('input[type=hidden]').each(function (i, item) {
    list.push($(item).val());
    if(list[i]==list[i+1]) {
        fun_toastr_notify('success', 'Please verify the document');
    } else {

    }
});
```

I am not able to compare each row of data. If all the values are the same then I only want to display my toaster message once. What logic should I use here? Thank you in advance.

I tried as below now.

```
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
    if(list[i]==list[i+1]) {
        fun_toastr_notify('success', 'Please verify the documents');
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that the toaster message will display more than one time. I want to display it only once if all elements are equal.

Comment: it worked by this logic.  for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
            {
                if(list[i]==list[i+1])
                {
                    var flag=true;
                }
            }
            if(flag==true)
                {
                fun_toastr_notify('success', 'Please verify the documents');
            }  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider putting this logic in the code that generates the viewmodel and output a flag to display the message, rather doing it while rendering the view.

This greatly simplifies your logic. An example:

```
public class YourModel {
    public List<ClientDetails> detailsbyclientId {get;set;}
    public bool AllClientsUnverified { get { return detailsbyclientId.All(client => client.currentStatus == "Unverified"); } }
}
```

And then in your view (inside a client `<script>` block)

```
if (@Model.AllClientsUnverified) {        
    fun_toastr_notify('success', 'Please verify the documents');
}
```